# como obtener mas de un parámetro en JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web, java-ee

Hola mi consulta es la siguiente

```
<a href="agregaramigo.jsp?id=<%=a.getId_amistad()%>">aceptar</a></P>
```

acá obtuve el id que necesitaba pero aparte

```
<%= a.getAmigo1()%>
```

pero también necesito capturar ese otro valor por la misma url de arriba

existe una manera de lograr eso

```
<div class="amigos post sticky">
        <h6>amigos</h6>
                    <%! AmigoMysqlDao amidao = new AmigoMysqlDao(){};%>
                    <% for(Amigos a:amidao.ver_amistad(user.getId())){%>
                    <P><i class="fas fa-user"></i> <%=a.getEmisor()%></P>

                    <%}%>
                    <h6>Quieren ser tu amigo</h6>


                    <% for(Amigos a:amidao.sin_amistad(user.getId())){%>

                    <P><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i><%=a.getEmisor()%> <a href="agregaramigo.jsp?id=<%=a.getId_amistad()%>">aceptar</a></P>
                    <%}%>
    </div>
```

desde otro jsp puedo capturar solo el id

```
    <%AmigoMysqlDao amidao = new AmigoMysqlDao(){};
amidao.agregar_amigo(???,user.getId(),Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
response.sendRedirect("muro.jsp");
%>
```

no se como capturar ese otro parámetro

de antemano muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes captuar varios parametros en la `url` concatenandolos con `&` pueden ser **n** cantidad de varibles que quieras enviar este seria un ejemplo:

```
<a href="agregaramigo.jsp?id=<%=a.getId_amistad()%>&parametro1=
<%=a.getNombre_amistad()%>">aceptar</a></P>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, resulto perfecto